# How to switch class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I got a question about switch a html tag's class in jQuery

Now, I have code like

```
<body>
    <button id="login" class="login">login</button>


    <script>
        jQuery(function($){

            $('.logout').click(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('logout');
                $(this).addClass('login');
                $(this).text('login');
                alert('logged out, ready to login');
            });

            $('.login').click(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('login');
                $(this).addClass('logout');
                $(this).text('logout');
                alert('logged in, ready to logout');
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I wonder **why** it always run $('.login').click no matter what class it has been.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The event is staying bound even after the class changes.
You can delegate the event to an element above it in the DOM and it will only run for classes matching the filter, like so:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $(document).on('click', '.logout', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('logout');
        $(this).addClass('login');
        $(this).text('login');
        alert('logged out, ready to login');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.login', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('login');
        $(this).addClass('logout');
        $(this).text('logout');
        alert('logged in, ready to logout');
    });

});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B4d9a/

Comment: If this answered your question please accept the answer so that @Corion gets credit for it.

Comment: @Kuan FYI - Additionally, you can chain jQuery functions like so: `$(this).removeClass('logout').addClass('login').text('login');` It will improve performance if you're doing a lot of different things to a single element and might make code more readable or maintainable. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
    $(document).on('click', '.logout', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('login logout').text('login');
            alert('logged out, ready to login');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.login', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('login logout').text('logout');
            alert('logged in, ready to logout');
    });
```

The `click` event listeners are only registered once, and when you do registration your button has class `login`. If you want it to use the `logout` listener later you'd need to update the listener. When your code runs, there is a `.login` button, but no `.logout` button, so the `.login` handler gets registered and the `.logout` handler just gets thrown away.

However, by using `$(document).on` you instead register *both* events on the `document` element, which always exists at load time, and it's automatically inherited by all child elements of the `document`. Using selectors lets us specify that we only want the event triggered when we click an element inside `document` with class `login` or `logout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 jQuery(function($){

        $('#login').click(function(){
          if($("#login").hasClass("logout"))
         {
            $(this).removeClass('logout');
            $(this).addClass('login');
            $(this).text('login');
            alert('logged out, ready to login');
        }
       else{
            $(this).removeClass('login');
            $(this).addClass('logout');
            $(this).text('logout');
            alert('logged in, ready to logout');
        }
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jkx8Q/)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use toggleClass() method of jQuery. 
Use it like this.

```
 $('#login').click(function(){

            if($(this).hasClass('login'))
            {
                  $(this).text('log in');
                  alert('logged in, ready to logout');
            }
            else
            {
                 $(this).text('logout');
                 alert('logged out, ready to login');
            }
             $(this).toggleClass('login');
        });
```

Comment: thanks, can you give me a little code for detail. I am really new to jQuery.

Comment: Its good to use toggle class as it also optimize your code. You don't need add or remove class every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
$('#login').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text($(this).hasClass('login') ? 'log out' : 'log in').toggleClass('login logout');
    alert($(this).hasClass('login') ? 'logged out. ready to log in.' : 'logged in. ready to log out.');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qWebw/

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to do it

```
$(document).on('click', '.login, .logout', function(){
    var current = this.className.match(/login|logout/)[0];
        // Detect the current button name & class ^ 

        opposite = current === 'login' ? 'logout' : 'login';
        // Get the opposite name & class ^ 

   $('.' + opposite).toggleClass('login logout').text(current);
   // Change the opposite ^ 

   $(this).toggleClass('login logout').text(opposite);
   // Change the Current ^

});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xwEMz/2)